# How to send "\" to a browser?

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys

I want to send `"\"` (backslash) key to a webpage in a browser.

I am able to send other keys. But it is not working for "`\`". I am using `SendKeys.SendWait("{\\}")` to send the key.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve? Since `\\\` doesn't do anything in the browser? Are you trying to send it to the Page?

Comment: @TFrost "browser" is not code. Please don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: Of course, in your case you'd use `Keys.OemBackslash`. But do note that `SendKeys` really isn't designed for sending *characters* - it's for sending *keys*. The two are very different and it's going to bite you hard on different keyboard layouts than US standard.

Comment: @CodeCaste sorry my mistake...

Comment: @Jamie Rees: yup..I am trying to send it to the page..i have edited the question

Comment: @Luaan: System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait() is accepting only string input and not an enum type. Am i doing something wrong ? and ya, I am using US standard layout always